# Attach source by clicking Attach Source below

Tags: java

I need to attach the `j2ee.jar` in my project , because I'm unable to access the class `ServletConfig` and the object init. The `j2ee.jar` says eclipse that is in the other project, any ideas, please? Should I use the button Attach Source and try to attach the source.

```
ServletConfig config;
super.init(config);
```

I cant access to `ServletConfig` and super.init

Comment: The problem is that im unable to access inside the jar to reach the classes, so my proyect wont compile.

Comment: Attaching source won't help you compile.  It will just let you see the source for the classes in the jar.